# BigQuery, left join

Tags: google-bigquery, left-join

I am stuck on a very simple SQL script. I want to do a LEFT JOIN on Google BigQuery.

> SELECT a.name, b.name FROM [bigquery-00000:table1] a LEFT JOIN
>   [bigquery-00000:table2] b ON b.name = a.name LIMIT 10

And I keep getting an error message:

> ON clause must be AND of = comparisons of one field name from each
>   table, with all field names prefixed with table name. Consider using
>   Standard SQL .google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/), which
>   allows non-equality JOINs and comparisons involving expressions and
>   residual predicates

I don't understand what is wrong with my script. Please help.

Comment: The query seems to be fine. How are you running this query? Is it through some API? WebUI? Also, have you tried running the Standard SQL to see if it works?

Answer (score 0):

I found what was wrong with my script. Wrong table name... sorry.